# How to set annotation field to process values with SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I need to set some of my fields in the annotated interface to accept Spring expression language definitions.

I have a working code, but I am not satisfied with this. See:

**Annotation:**

```java
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
public @interface Example {
    String id();
}
```

**Aspect:**

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class ExampleAspect {
    @Before("@annotation(com.example.annotation.Example)")
    public void beforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint) {

        MethodSignature signature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        Example p = signature.getMethod().getAnnotation(Example.class);
        long id = (Long) valueFromExpression(joinPoint, p.id());
        // .... work with ID
    }

    /**
     * Manually processed SpEL expression
     */
    private Object valueFromExpression(JoinPoint joinPoint, String expression) {
        ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

        StandardEvaluationContext context = new StandardEvaluationContext();
        CodeSignature codeSignature = (CodeSignature) joinPoint.getSignature();
        String[] parameterNames = codeSignature.getParameterNames();
        Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();

        for (int i = 0; i < parameterNames.length; i++) {
            context.setVariable(parameterNames[i], args[i]);
        }

        Expression exp = parser.parseExpression(expression);

        return exp.getValue(context);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```java
@GetMapping("/test/{someId}")
@Example(id = "#someId")
public void example(@PathVariable Long someId) {
   // some code
}
```

This works, but I want to define initialization of annotation properties as automatically processed by SpEL and also properly highlighted by my IDE - without method `valueFromExpression()`

Answer (score 0):

Regarding IDE support, see this answer from [@StéphaneNicoll]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33298418/3759414

> "The support in Intellij is the same thing. Currently Jetbrains devs
>   track the places where SpEL is used and mark them for SpEL support. We
>   don't have any way to conduct the fact that the value is an actual
>   SpEL expression (this is a raw java.lang.String on the annotation type
>   after all)."